# I have a table named dmp with 4 columns, I want to query selected data from a column call by parent id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: table]

I have a table named dmp with 4 columns(id, name, dtype and parent), I want to query specific data from a column call by parent id.

I want to display parent name 'nill' in parent column when choose division from dtype column and also want to display all parent name like Ramna, Dhanmondi when choose thana from dtype column. how it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN d.dtype = 'Division' THEN 'nil'
    ELSE (SELECT name FROM dmp WHERE id = d.parent)
    END AS name
FROM dmp d
```